# select column index by percentage of last row

Tags: pandas

I am trying to extract the top % of the last row value in dataframe.

```
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
{
'u':[6,7,11],
'v':[4,7,1],
'w':[0,4,7],
'x':[1,3,5],
'y':[2,1,6],
'z':[3,9,8],
})

pct=40 #40%
val=int((pct*.01)*len(df.columns))
s=df.iloc[-1].nlargest(val)

print (df[s.keys())
```

I was wondering if this is the correct way.

Comment: Do you just want the values from your last row, or all rows and just the columns of interest? You're description and output are a little confusing

Comment: i want the rows and columns of interest.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need:

```
pct=40 #40%
val=int((pct*.01)*len(df.columns))
df = df.loc[:, df.iloc[-1].nlargest(val).index]
print (df)
    u  z
0   6  3
1   7  9
2  11  8
```

Solution with [`numpy.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) for positions by sorted data, select last columns in inverse order and pass to `iloc`:

```
pct=40 #40%
val=int((pct*.01)*len(df.columns))

df = df.iloc[:, df.iloc[-1].argsort()[:-val - 1:-1]]
print (df)
    u  z
0   6  3
1   7  9
2  11  8
```